# Why does not regex_match throw a error when my regex is invalid?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I wrote a code like this `regex_match("ab","a**b")` and it returns true.
As we know, "a**b" is a invalid regex, isn't it?--At least it is invalid in https://regex101.com/ .
I try to catch a exception but nothing happened. It just performed as "a**b" is a valid regex expression.
Nothing happened too when I try to use regex_search.
I wonder if I misuse this function or there is a bug in the regex library.

Comment: What makes you think it would throw an error? Did you check the return value of [`regex_match`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match)

Comment: @Tas one would expect an `std::regex_error` from [`std::regex` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex) when regex is incorrect, and [clang indeed throws](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NLyPoz1iHRtinwJ7) an exception, but [gcc doesn't](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RKhoUfiTBB8B35XN). OP's code won't compile, but it's fixed simply enough with `regex_match("ab",std::regex("a**b"));`.